# My custom view is being clipped if its position is not (0,0)

Tags: android, view

My problem is that if i set the Y-axis of my view to anything but 0 its drawn region gets clipped from the top. Using log traces i've discovered that the view bounds (and its drawable's bounds) are always the correct position. I've tried clipChildren=false, but that gave me a stranger behavior where the drawn region and the views bounds are not in sync. Here's all pertinent code to my view

```
//onMeasure
  @Override
  public void onMeasure(int w, int h){
   int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(w);
  //minHeight is 48dp scaled for density
  setMeasuredDimension(width, minHeight);
  }


//onDraw
//Note that i've ommited the log statements, however they return the correct
//coordinates for the view Rect   
  @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas c){ 
   c.drawRect(trackRect, tempPaint);
  }

//onLayout
@Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    trackRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
    mTrack.setBounds(trackRect);  //irrelevant atm
}

//XML CODE

//BELOW draws a perfect rectangle with a width of match_parent and a height       
//of 48dp

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:clipChildren="false" >


<com.bryanstudios.bryan.clock.LocationSwitch
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

//BELOW will cause clipping
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

<com.bryanstudios.bryan.clock.LocationSwitch
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

//BELOW causes the view to disappear entirely
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

<com.bryanstudios.bryan.clock.LocationSwitch
    android:align_parent_bottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My best guess is my onMeasure isn't done properly. Also note again that regardless of where i position the view (via w/ margins or LayoutParam attributes) the logical positioning of the view is accurate, yet the drawn region is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
   trackRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
   ...
```

The left/top/etc params here are relative to the parent.  If your view's y position == 0, top also == 0.  If you change the view's Y position relative to its parent, top is set to that same value.  You are then assigning this top to the rect you draw.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c){ 
   c.drawRect(trackRect, tempPaint);
   ...
```

This will draw a rectangle with the same offsets you have specified in onLayout.  This means that it will begin drawing `trackRect.top` from the top of the view.

If you just want the actual size of the view, `view.getWidth()` and `view.getHeight()` are likely all that is needed; if you want to initialise something (like a Path) when the width and height of the view are known, override `onSizeChanged()` and do it in there instead of in `onLayout()`.

Comment: It's funny because i actually about positioning being relative to the parent but didn't make much of it lol. Thanks for your help, tom!

Comment: You're welcome fella. :)  Hit the 'answered' tick if you're happy with my answer.

Comment: where is the appropriate place to initialize the views Rect then?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve - if you just want to know what the size of the view is to initialise a rect, you'll get it in `onSizeChanged()`.  Set the rect's `top` and `left` to 0, and its `right` and `bottom` to `width` and `height`, respectively.